# Edge Browser Hide Default File Upload

Tags: c#, css, blazor

I have an open source project and Nuget package called DataJuggler.Blazor.FileUpload
(https://github.com/DataJuggler/BlazorFileUpload)

Using Chrome, the following works to show a custom button for the File Upload:

```
 <FileUpload CustomSuccessMessage="Your file uploaded successfully." OnChange="OnFileUploaded"
    OnReset="OnReset" ResetButtonClassName="localbutton"
    ShowStatus="false"  PartialGuidLength="10" MaxFileSize=@UploadLimit FilterByExtension="true" 
    ShowCustomButton="true"  ButtonText="Start" CustomButtonClassName="startbutton" 
    AllowedExtensions=".jpg;.png;" ShowResetButton="false" 
    CustomExtensionMessage="Only .jpg and .png files are allowed." 
    AppendPartialGuid="true" InputFileClassName="customfileupload" 
    FileTooLargeMessage=@FileTooLargeMessage>
</FileUpload>

.customfileupload
{  
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    height:48px;
    min-height: 48px;
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

.startbutton
{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0px;
    outline: none;
    background-image: url('../images/StartButton.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    top: 36vh;
    left: 50%;
    width: 28%;
    height: 28%;
    background-size: 100%;
    margin-left: -14%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

And this bit of CSS hides the default file input on Chrome

```
input[type=file], /* FF, IE7+, chrome (except button) */
input[type=file]::-webkit-file-upload-button 
{ /* chromes and blink button */
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
```

On Chrome the standard file input is hidden, but on Edge it shows:

[image]

Thanks, I don't use Edge often but I would like to know how to fix it for users that do.

Comment: Even I cannot test it in edge, so can you try this in your `input` type css :  background-color: transparent;
 color: red;
 font-size: 40px;
 margin: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
 transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
 cursor: pointer;

Comment: have you tried just using the "hidden" attribute on the input - should work in all current browsers... https://caniuse.com/#search=hidden

Comment: Mr. Magoo, I just tried your solution and it worked. I was trying to use all CSS is why I waited a week after your answer, but instead I just refactored my component to have a if ( Visible ) I show it without the Hidden Attribute, and if Visible is false I show it with hidden attribute. Thank you very much, I am posting in the answer section just so I can paste a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mr. Magoo, I refactored my component to use the hidden attribute or not, based on a visible parameter:

```
[Parameter] public bool Visible { get; set; } = true;
```

Then in the mark up I render it or not based on the value of Visible:

```
@if (Visible)
{
    <input type="file" class="@InputFileClassName" @ref="inputFileElement" 
            @attributes="UnmatchedParameters" />
}
else
{
    <input type="file" class="@InputFileClassName" @ref="inputFileElement" 
            @attributes="UnmatchedParameters" hidden />
}
```

And I added a Visible Property to my wrapper component, and to use it now I set Visible=false for the cases I don't want the default input to appear, and it works on Chrome and Edge. I haven't tested Firefox, but I imagine it will work there also.

Thanks again to Mr. Magoo. It is funny, in regards to anyone who has ever bet on me playing 9 ball or one pocket, Mr. Magoo was one of the nicer things I used to hear.